# Relation between static constant member variables and narrowing conversions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, static

Coding in C++20, using a GCC compiler.

Based on the code shown below, the program will raise a narrowing conversion error/warning due to the `int` to `char` implicit conversion. However, if I add `static const/constexpr` to the `int var {92};` line, the program runs without raising any errors/warnings.

1. Why does this happen?
2. When should I be using `static const/constexpr` member variables?
3. Why are `constexpr` member variables not allowed?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    private:
        int var {92};
    public:
        void bar() {
            char chr {var};
            std::cout << chr << '\n';
        }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11) prohibits [narrowing conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions).

(emphasis mine)

> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, **except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type**

If you declare `var` as `static const/constexpr`, it becomes a constant expression and the value `92` could be stored in `char`, then the code works fine.